# how to send email to administrator when someone edit post

Tags: custom-post-types

I made custom-post-type(book). And in my site, anyone can register and write book(custom-post-type) and also edit this book post-type. 
And I want to get email-alarm when someone edit their book post-type. 
Is there some ways to code like this without plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Without a plugin? No. WordPress doesn't do that. With code? Sure, but that's a plugin. So why no plugin?

Comment: too much plugins make my site slow. (my site is slow enough). so if I can solve a problem with a short code, I want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in Wordpress.org you have a example to do that:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post

Look also here to see when it modified
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Regards.